# How do I make a DBIx::Class relationship with a fixed join condition?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

We have a link table that can handle multiple types of object on one side, and I can't work out how to get from one of these objects to the link table using has_many.

Example: link table contains:

> ```
> id link_id link_table resource_id
> 1  1       page       3
> 2  1       page       5
> 3  2       page       3
> 4  1       not_page   1
> ```

Building the relationship from the resource side is easy enough:

```
Resource->has_many(links => 'Link', 'resource_id');
```

but I haven't been able to get the corresponding relationship from the page side:

```
Page->has_many(links => 'Link', 'link_id');
```

would get the not_page link

```
Page->has_many(links => 'Link', {'foreign.link_id' => 'self.id', 'foreign.link_table' => 'page'});
```

gives an 'Invalid rel cond val page' error (which was not that surprising to me).

```
Page->has_many(links => 'Link', {'foreign.link_id' => 'self.id', 'foreign.link_table' => '"page"'});
```

gives an 'Invalid rel cond val "page"' error. Throwing backslashes in didn't help.

[DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class::Relationship::Base#add_relationship) says:

> The condition needs to be an [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SQL%3A%3AAbstract)-style representation of the join between the tables

and I have tried various different options from there, such as:

```
Page->has_many(links => 'Link', {'foreign.link_id' => 'self.id', 'foreign.link_table' => {'=', 'page'}});
```

but without any success at all.

If I added another field to the page table which always contains the value 'page' I could do

```
Page->has_many(links => 'Link', {'foreign.link_id' => 'self.id', 'foreign.link_table' => 'self.what_table_am_i'});
```

but that's hardly an optimal solution.

Splitting the link table into a separate one for each type may be a possibility, but this is an existing project that is being considered for adaptation to DBIx::Class, and there may be other places where splitting a table into multiple other tables is more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Do you want "belongs_to" on the other side of "has_many"?

Comment: The has_many was more important, so I elected not to add more complications to the question than necessary. I hope Brian's answer is able to be modified for the belongs_to case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just make a wrapper method that calls the relationship with the required arguments:

```
Page->has_many(__all_links => 'Link', 'link_id');

sub links {
    shift->__all_links({link_table => 'page'});
}
```

This would be pretty easy to turn into a DBIx::Class component if you have multiple tables that need to have this kind of join logic.

Comment: And how then this may be used with search()? I tried: $c->model('Page')->search(undef, {prefetch => "links"})->all; But it says: DBIx::Class::ResultSet::all(): No such relationship links on Page

Answer (score 1):

It can be specified in the has_many call like so:

```
Page->has_many(links => 'Link', 'link_id',
                    { where => { link_table => 'page'} });
```

See: [DBIx::Class Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/~frew/DBIx-Class-0.08123/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Filtering_a_relationship_result_set)